# Is using the /3GB statup switch in Windows 2008 x64 only running Sql Server 2008 x64, a good thing?

Tags: windows-server-2008, sql-server, sql-server-2008, switch

there's plenty of articles that explain the use of the **/3GB startup switch**. The general explanation is ..

> Regardless of the amount of physical
>   memory in your system, Windows uses a
>   virtual address space of 4 GB, with 2
>   GB allocated to user-mode processes
>   (for example, applications) and 2 GB
>   allocated to kernel-mode processes
>   (for example, the operating system and
>   kernel-mode drivers). On systems that
>   have 1 GB or more of physical memory,
>   these two startup switches can be used
>   to allocate more memory to
>   applications (3 GB) and less memory to
>   the operating system (1 GB).

Ok - that's not hard to understand. ... ... but is this a good thing for a Sql Server? Is the answer dependant upon how much *total* memory exists in the server?

For this discussion can we relate any answers to

1. **4 GB** ram
2. **16 GB** ram

... with a server containing **Windows 2008 standard x64** + **Sql Server 2008 x64**. I hope the # of processors don't impact the answer :P

So i suppose i'm asking, does Sql Server require a lot of ram for OS + kernal mode drivers?

Comment: I suggest you also to read answers to the similar question http://serverfault.com/questions/27352/are-there-any-drawbacks-of-3gb-switch-in-boot-ini-for-32bit-windows

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The /3GB switch does not apply to 64-bit editions of Windows

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/294418

> Applications that are compiled with
>   the /LARGEADDRESSAWARE option, as
>   would be required to take advantage of
>   the /3GB switch in 32-bit Windows,
>   will automatically be able to address
>   4 GB of virtual memory without any
>   boot time switches or changes to x64
>   Windows. Plus, of course, the
>   operating system does not have to
>   share that 4 GB of space. Therefore,
>   it is not constrained at all

and

> A pool of system Page Table Entries
>   (PTEs) that is used to map system
>   pages such as I/O space, Kernel
>   stacks, and memory descriptor lists.
>   64-bit programs use a 16-terabyte
>   tuning model (8 terabytes User and 8
>   terabytes Kernel). 32-bit programs
>   still use the 4-GB tuning model (2 GB
>   User and 2 GB Kernel). This means that
>   32-bit processes that run on 64-bit
>   versions of Windows run in a 4-GB
>   tuning model (2 GB User and 2GB
>   Kernel). **64-bit versions of Windows do
>   not support the use of the /3GB switch
>   in the boot options.** Theoretically, a
>   64-bit pointer could address up to 16
>   exabytes. 64-bit versions of Windows
>   have currently implemented up to 16
>   terabytes of address space

Answer (score 3):

With SQL Server the more memory the better.  SQL Server will pretty much take what ever you can give it.  You'll want to reserve at least 1 Gig for the OS, and leave the rest for SQL Server.

Because its the 64bit OS you won't need the 3GB or AWE switches for the OS.