# Is using the /3GB statup switch in Windows 2008 x86 only running Sql Server 2008 x86, a good thing?

Tags: windows-server-2008, sql-server, sql-server-2008, pae

I previously [asked this same question](https://serverfault.com/questions/34280/is-using-the-3gb-statup-switch-in-windows-2008-x64-only-running-sql-server-2008) a while back but that was for the x64 bit versions of the OS and Sql Server.

Now, I'm asking the same thing for the x86 (32 bit) versions of the OS and Sql Server.

So, is this a good thing to do? I'm assuming I would want to give my sql server as much ram as possible and the OS as little as possible.

Thoughts?

Comment: I thought this question looked familiar...

Comment: :) yeah ... but now i've got a different server on different hardware, to support :P

Comment: How much physical memory is in the server and what's the size of your database(s)?

Comment: Server has 4Gig exactly, fwiw.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the server has less than 16GB and 4GB or more then yes /3GB switch is a *good thing*, don't forget /3GB's ugly sister /PAE, see table below.

If the server has more than 16GB then its a bad thing, as 2GB of kernel memory is required to manage the AWE address space.

In summary:

```
 -----------------------
|Memory (GB) | Switches |
|-----------------------|
| <4GB       | none     |
|  4GB       | /3GB     |
|  >4GB-16GB | /3GB /PAE|
|  >16GB     | /PAE     |
 -----------------------
```

to implement this on a Windows Server 2008 box, use the BCDEdit command:

```
bcdedit /set IncreaseUserVa 3072
```

Comment: +1, I witnessed a server having Pain and Suffering with 18 GB, /3GB and /PAE.

Comment: Never been keen on having both /3GB and /PAE (as shown on your 4GB-16GB range) as it potentially squishes the OS too much - would recommend only /PAE in that scenario.

Comment: those are recommended MS settings, just have to find a source. that table is from my brain so it may be wrong or out of date for win 2008

Comment: +1 - It was always a pain trying to dig these numbers up when setting up a new SQL server.

Comment: Hi Nick, if I have a 32 bit server with say 8GB - I only set the PAE flag and configure AWE. Also setting /3GB cuts the kernal space in half - possibly causing stability issues in certain instances. See this link - http://blogs.technet.com/askperf/archive/2007/03/23/memory-management-demystifying-3gb.aspx

Answer (score 1):

See this link http://blogs.msdn.com/chadboyd/archive/2007/03/24/pae-and-3gb-and-awe-oh-my.aspx

Answer (score 0):

On x64 the switch is totally useless, as memory is managed ***quite*** differently than x86 systems.

On x86 it can be rather useful, as long as you actually ***have*** more than 3GB physical memory, of course.

Just be a little careful, because that switch forces Windows to only give 1GB virtual memory to the kernel, so if it needs more than that for whatever reason (f.e. managing more than 16 GB physical memory, as Nick said) you're running into troubles.

Answer (score 0):

Also see [this thread](https://serverfault.com/questions/44446/3gb-switch-on-win2k3-server-with-6gb-ram-and-pae) for good general information on the /3GB switch.

Disclaimer: Yes, it is a question I posted